# Dynamically update bookmark Power BI

Tags: filter, powerbi, dashboard, datefilter

I’m working on a dashboard where I am looking to daily update a historical fact table with the newest data of the day before. I have a filter where you can select the preferred date (one selection only allowed) for each page. Because there are quite some dates in the dataset, I would like to add a sort of bookmark-button that sets the date filter to the most recent date. However, I’m struggling to make this happen. Is there a way to do this dynamically, without having to update a bookmark daily by hand?

Thanks a lot in advance!

I tried using a bookmark but I am not able to set the filter dynamically

Answer (score 0):

You may not be able to dynamically change the filter default value with or without bookmark.  However, you can create a text column, call it SelectionDate, that is the same as your date column.  In your Power Query (M), update the latest date's value to something like "Current".  Use this field as your selection value in your filter and set the filter to "Current".  You will have your report always set to the current date.